# Sending JSON arrays over Arduino Ethernet - only works for 0s

Tags: json, tcp, arduino, ethernet

First and foremost, I apologize for any statements that don't make technical sense, I'm a first-year EE student and I don't fully understand everything I'm doing.

For a robotics project I am trying to feed an Arduino values to control motors, and I'm sending the Arduino the values via JSON arrays. The Arduino (with an Ethernet Shield) acts as a client, and my laptop acts as a server. I parse a JSON array with simple values (X:400, Y:200, Z:0, etc), and send it over the connection. My issue is that, for any set of values other than (X:0, Y:0, Z:0, etc), the connection lags. The connection doesn't STOP (I have debug statements to catch that), it simply hangs there. Nothing happens after that point - the server and the client just kind of wait forever.

I really need to get this working, so I was hoping somebody with experience with this sort of thing could walk me through what I'm doing wrong? The following is the full Arduino sketch I'm using.

The encoding/decoding with JSON occurs in the loop of the sketch, for clarity's sake.

```c++
#include <QuadMotorShields.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

QuadMotorShields md;

StaticJsonBuffer<100> jsonBuffer; //the JSON buffer we write/call from
StaticJsonBuffer<100> clearJson; //an empty JSON buffer

// To obtain server ip: Go to network settings->properties->IpV4 
// Make sure arduino's ip matches for first three numbers or else
// connections will fail.

byte server[] = {211, 255, 132, 121};
byte ip[] = {211, 255, 132, 49};

byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0E, 0x40, 0x9F};
int port = 1900;

int x,y,z;  
String s = " ";
EthernetClient client;
int count = 0;


void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);

   Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
   delay(1000);

   Serial.println("connecting...");

   // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
   client.connect(server, port);
}

/* loop()
 * Reads message from client char by char and saves to a string.
 * This string is parsed into a json object using ArduinoJson.
 * The values for various variables is then obtained from this object. 
 * Using these various variables we control the robot! */

void loop()
{
   count++;
   if (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      if(c == '~') {
         int maxCommandLength = 70;
         char command[maxCommandLength];
         s.toCharArray(command, maxCommandLength);  
         JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(command);
         //Serial.print("JSON OBJECT: ");
         root.printTo(Serial);
         x = root["X"];
         y = root["Y"];
         //r = root["R"];
         z = root["Z"];

         md.setM1Speed(x);
         md.setM2Speed(y);
         md.setM3Speed(z);
         md.setM4Speed(z);
         jsonBuffer = clearJson;
         s = " ";
      }
      else {
         s += String(c);
      }
   }
   else { //client is no longer available
      client.connect(server, port);
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you post what the server is sending the client? From the code it looks like it is a combination of JSON and '~' characters.

Comment: Note that `client.available()` returns the number of bytes which can be read from the connection. If this returns zero it doesn't necessarily mean that the connection has become unusable it just means that there are no characters to read at that moment. Depending on how the server is sending data, the call to `client.connect()` in the `else` block may be causing the problem you are seeing.

Comment: The actual problem, as it turns out, was one of the motor control functions we were using somehow stopped the Arduino code when it was called, cause it called a bad pin or something. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem!